# Finding vertices of a polytope with a given set of inequalities.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, computational-geometry, polytopes, discrete-geometry

I am given a set of inequalities $v_1\ge v_2\ge \cdots\ge v_n\ge 0$, and a set of bounds for the coordinates: $v_k\in[0,a_k],\ 1\le k\le n$, where $a_1\ge a_2\ge \cdots\ge a_n\ge 0$. My question is:

> What are the vertices of the polytope created by these set of constraints?

I think that the coordinates of the vertices are going to be given by $(0,0,\cdots,0),(a_1,0,\cdots,0),(a_2,a_2,0,\cdots,0),\cdots,(a_n,a_n,\cdots,a_n)$, and $(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n)$. I could not rigorously find this, but guessed this should be the result after finding the coordinates for 2 dimension, and interpolating the result for higher dimensions. However, I want to know, first of all, whether this result is correct, and how to find this result rigorously for any dimension. Please help me out.

Comment: You should be careful here. The vertices of the polytope are still elements of the polytope. They should be legal vertices. For example, $(a_2,a_2,0,\dots,0)$ is not legal because that implies $v_1 = a_2 \notin [0,a_1]$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow, how do you say $a_2\notin [0,a_1]$? I already have the inequality $a_1\ge a_2$. This should make $(a_2,a_2,0,\cdots,0)$ a legal vertex, right?

Comment: You're right. I misread the inequality. Sorry!

Comment: Is each $a_k\geq 0$?

Comment: @ayberk, yes, $a_n\ge 0$. I have added that to the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [marked order polytope](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2365) as introduced by Ardila, Bliem and Salazar as a generalization of the order polytope by Stanley. The face structure (in particular vertices) is discussed in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01393) in terms of partitions of the underlying poset.

In your case I think you are missing vertices: for $n=4$ you get a vertex $(a_2,a_2,a_4,a_4)$ for example.

Letting $a_{n+1}=0$, the full list of vertices should be those points of the form $(a_{i_1},a_{i_2},\dots,a_{i_n})$ with indices $i_k\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ satisfying

- $i_k \ge k$,
- $i_k \le i_{k+1}$,
- for all $j\in\{i_1,\dots,i_n\}$ we have $i_j=j$.

A constructive description of these is the following: In the last coordinate pick either $0$ or $a_n$, then inductively for the $k$-th coordinate with $k=n-1,n-2,...,1$ pick either the value you picked for $k+1$ or pick $a_k$.

By this description we have $2^n$ vertices, assuming that the $a_j$ are all distinct.

---

Note that this example is also unimodularly equivalent to the Stanley–Pitman polytope, as discussed in [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190508/marked-chain-polytope-has-this-been-studied).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Do you know if there is an explicit solution for the problem I posted, and whether my guess is correct, thanks?

Comment: I already gave an example of a vertex you are missing. I now edited my answer to include the full characterization of vertices.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the full answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Note that I just added a missing condition.

Comment: Ok, thanks again!

Comment: Added a more intuitive description and the number of vertices.

Comment: Is my approach correct? It will be great if you can kindly verify. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have asked the question separately [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134883/request-for-verification-of-the-technique-for-deducing-vertices-of-a-polytope). Please have a look.

Comment: Hi, Can you kindly have a look at another problem that I have asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/329925/how-to-find-the-vertices-of-the-set-v-i-in-mathbbra-1-ge-v-1-ge-v-2-ge-c)? Although it is related to this problem, I cannot figure out how to proceed solving it. It is related to my research and I need to find the answer to this urgently because the next main stage is critically dependent upon it. So it would be very helpful if you can give your comments on the problem.Thanks.